# Memory allocation for stack & Heap

Tags: java, memory-management

When i specify memory using xms and xmx then is it allocation memory only for heap or it includes memory for all purposes?

Issue i have is , if xmx is only for heap then how do we restrict total memory allocation for java?

And say if i specify xss option then will this be in adition to xmx allocation?

Comment: Memory allocated to the stack and memory allocated to the heap are treated separately, yes.

Comment: @perception: But say i just specify xmx option then will stack get it memory out of xmx? If not then how can i restrict total memory allocation to jvm?

Comment: If you omit the stack size it will use a platform and VM appropriate default. The memory allocated for the stack is in addition to the memory allocated for the heap. If you override the default stack size with -xss then you are effectively setting the total memory to be used by the program.

Comment: @perception: I understand you point about default value but will it take this memory chunk out of xmx? or it will be in addition to xmx?

Comment: No, it will be another allocation of memory, separate from what is allocated to the heap.